# Configuring auctex for pdf viewer

Tags: texlive, emacs, auctex

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10, Emacs 24.3.50.1, TeX Live 2013, AucTeX 11.87.2 (from ELPA). I've followed the instructions given by this page [on enabling Okular](http://mathieu.3maisons.org/wordpress/how-to-configure-emacs-and-auctex-to-work-with-a-pdf-viewer)  (I'd rather use Evince, though), but this doesn't seem to work. `C-c C-c` on an opened .tex file, gives me the choice `Command: (default) LaTeX` in the minibuffer, then again and the minibuffer returns, so I would have to type in a viewer name. I type okular . . . and nothing -- that is, Okular starts, but there's no pdf of the tex showing. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: It's late and I'll need to pick this up again tomorrow, but the two variables you probably need to configure are as follows:  `TeX-view-program-list` and `TeX-view-program-selection`.  However, I use OSX instead of Linux.  I'm sure someone will have an answer before I wake up, but you can Google those two variables in the meantime.  My limited public user history of questions and answers on this forum also have examples of how to use those variables (but in the context of OSX).

Comment: Use this in your `.emacs` file: `(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("View" "evince %g" TeX-run-command nil t :help "Run evince on your document"))`. Then do `C-c C-c`, type View and enter.

Comment: This produced an error: "Symbol's value as variable is void: TeX-command-list"

Comment: Okay, I amended (eval-after-load "tex" '(...)) to your suggestion, zeroth, but now I get Evince to open, but with 'Unable to open document "file:///home/me/mytexstuff/%g” instead of the Hallo.pdf. Any ideas what the proper format should be?

Answer (score 3):

This addition to my .emacs finally did the trick:

```
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn
     (setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Evince" "evince --page-index=%(outpage) %o")))
     ;(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("View" "evince %g" TeX-run-command nil t :help "Run evince on your document"))
     (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Evince")))))
```

Note commented out suggestion from above. Got the basics from [this discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/253525/emacs-auctex-how-do-i-open-the-pdf-in-evince-at-the-current-cursor-position)